# Duplicate environment variable in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I have two PATHS declared in zsh. How does this happen / or how can I reproduce it?

```
~ ❯ env | grep -i path
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Comment: Which `PATH` (if either, considering that other guy's answer) do you get if you simply type `echo $PATH`?

Comment: I get the first one. However ruby scripts read the second PATH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are lots ways of reproducing this output.

Cosmetically with line feeds:

```
% export foo=$'1\nfoo=2'
% env | grep foo
foo=1
foo=2
```

Cosmetically with carriage returns:

```
export foo=1
export bar=$'2\rfoo'
```

Cosmetically with non-printable characters:

```
env foo=1 $'foo\x01=2' zsh
```

But the most fun and interesting way is to actually set multiple variables by the same name.

People often don't realize that the environment doesn't consist of variables at all. It's just a list of arbitrary strings that is conventionally but not necessarily interpretted as `key=value` pairs.

We can simply add two strings `foo=1` and `foo=2`, and it's up to the program to figure out how to interpret that. One way of doing this is a small C program:

```
int main() {
  char *argv[] = { "zsh", 0 };
  char *envp[] = { "foo=1", "foo=2", 0 };
  execvpe("zsh", argv, envp);
}
```

When executed, we're put into a shell with both values set:

```
% env | grep foo
foo=1
foo=2
```

You can inspect the output of `env -0 | od -c` to see which of the above you're currently experiencing.

---

As a bonus, let's ask `zsh` and `bash` what they think the value of `$foo` is when it's found twice:

```
% echo $foo
1
% bash -c 'echo $foo'
2
```

They each pick a different string from the environment.

Imagine if security depended on a `zsh` wrapper filtering environment variables for a `bash` script!

This is one of the many, many reasons why one should never try to reinvent `sudo`.

Comment: Nicely explained. Thanks.

Comment: Are you just generally advising not to naively reimplement any security component of a complex system, or does `sudo` specifically have protection against shadow environment variables?

Comment: `sudo` specifically protects against this, and many other environment based issues.